# Highlight textarea on the fly

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to highlight text in a textarea by specifying a background color and a range of indexes. I'll then be constantly changing and updating the highlighted text dynamically as the user types.

[jquery.highlightTextarea](http://mistic100.github.io/jquery-highlighttextarea/) is almost perfect. The problem is that it appears that it wasn't really designed to update the highlighted text on the fly like this. And in addition to that, the author has now discontinued it and won't be updating it anymore.

I even went so far as to look at [Ace Code Editor](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=about), but the ability to highlight based on simple indexes wasn't really there with that one (you have to highlight based on the rows/columns). Plus it seemed like it was overkill for what I'm doing.

So I'm looking for alternatives. In addition to the features I mentioned, performance is high on my list of priorities as well. I'd like to compile a list of libraries to consider. Any suggestions?

Comment: @charlietfl - I mean being able to send new index ranges after every key press. So tearing down the DOM object and re-initializing wouldn't be ideal (I could do that now). Preferably I'd just send new index ranges and the highlighting would change.

Comment: Where do the indexes that define the highlight come from? are they bound to keyword in the text?

Comment: @MartinStaufcik - They come from an AJAX call as a result from a regex. So you could have all the e's in a sentence highlighted, for example, but all I'm supplying are index ranges.

Comment: Would it not be possible to evaluate the highlight only in javascript, without the ajax roundtrip (in case the highlight should update immediatelly as the user types)?

Comment: @MartinStaufcik - The tool will have a JavaScript only mode. This particular problem relates to the .NET mode which must be performed server-side since Silverlight is dying off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured something out that's working well for me. I'm using the [Ace Editor](https://ace.c9.io/). I went back and forth between Ace and CodeMirror, and finally settled on Ace because I felt like this particular task was a little more straightforward and the documentation is better too. I say straightforward, but the complication is that I have to convert index ranges into column / row ranges because that's the format the `Range` object in Ace is expecting.

But here's what I came up with:

```
function HighlightMatches(matches) {
    var matchClass = "myMarker";
    var oldMarkers = inputEditor.session.$backMarkers;

    // clear out old markers
    for (var prop in oldMarkers) {
        if (oldMarkers[prop].clazz == matchClass) {
            inputEditor.session.removeMarker(oldMarkers[prop].id);
        }
    }

    if (matches && matches.length > 0) {
        var ranges = NormalizedRanges(GetInput(), matches);

        // add new markers
        for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
            inputEditor.session.addMarker(new Range(ranges[i].startRow, ranges[i].startCol, ranges[i].endRow, ranges[i].endCol), matchClass);
        }
    }
}    

function NormalizedRanges(input, matches) {
    var ranges = [];

    var startCol = 0;
    var endCol = 0;
    var startRow = 0;
    var endRow = 0;
    var currentMatch = 0;

    var matchStart = 0;
    var matchLength = 0;
    var matchEnd = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        matchStart = matches[currentMatch].index;
        matchLength = matches[currentMatch].length;
        matchEnd = matchStart + matchLength;            

        // process match
        if (i >= matchStart && i <= matchEnd) {
            endCol = startCol;
            endRow = startRow;

            for (var k = 0; k < matchLength; k++) {
                endCol++;
                var advanceNewLine = AdvanceNewLine(input.substr(i + k, 2))
                if (advanceNewLine > 0) {
                    endRow++;
                    endCol = 0;
                    if (advanceNewLine == 2)
                        k++;
                }
            }

            ranges.push(new IndexRange(startCol, endCol, startRow, endRow));

            startCol = endCol;
            startRow = endRow;

            // set index to end of match
            i = matchEnd - 1;

            // advance current match
            currentMatch++;
            if (currentMatch == matches.length)
                return ranges;
        }
        else {
            // advance range
            startCol++;
            var advanceNewLine = AdvanceNewLine(input.substr(i, 2));
            if (advanceNewLine > 0) {
                startRow++;
                startCol = 0;
                if (advanceNewLine == 2)
                    i++;
            }
        }
    }

    return ranges;
}

function AdvanceNewLine(text) {
    if (text == '\r\n')
        return 2;
    else {
        var char = text.charAt(0);
        if (char == '\n' || text == '\r')
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }           
}

function IndexRange(startCol, endCol, startRow, endRow) {
    this.startCol = startCol;
    this.endCol = endCol;
    this.startRow = startRow;
    this.endRow = endRow;
}
```

You simply call `HighlightMatches` and pass in a `matches` JSON object that might look something like this:

```
{"matches":[{"index":0,"length":1},{"index":4,"length":1}]}
```